# SonarQube Analysis for Asp.Net Website Project

Tags: asp.net, sonarqube

I am trying to add my Asp.Net Website solution for SonarQube Analysis. 
In this solution, We have 1 main website project and other class library project referred by this main Website project. 
Analysis runs fine and I can see all referred class library projects in analysis report site. But I am not seeing main website project.

My guess is as this website is not generating any dll, analysis is not happening. Anyone seen this issue? please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found, as per sonar website, its not supported.

https://docs.sonarqube.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#AnalyzingwithSonarQubeScannerforMSBuild-KnownLimitations

Comment: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Scanning+on+Windows

Analysis of Web Site projects is not supported, however analysis of Web Application projects is supported.